# Possible to GROUP BY across different columns in mariadb/mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb, group-by, gaps-and-islands

I have a table full of events similar to this:

```
`date`     | start_time | end_time | length 
--------------------------------------------
2022-01-10 | 07:00:00   | 16:00:00 |      9
2022-01-11 | 07:00:00   | 16:00:00 |      9
2022-01-11 | 16:00:00   | 20:00:00 |      5
2022-01-12 | 07:00:00   | 12:00:00 |      5
2022-01-12 | 16:00:00   | 20:00:00 |      5
```

I want to group by contiguous events on each date. See how on 2022-01-11 there are two entries, one ending at the same time the next one starts? (but not on 12th)

I'd like to get something like this:

```
select `date`, SUM(length) from events
group by `date`, ????

`date`     | length
--------------------
2022-01-10 |      9
2022-01-11 |     14
2022-01-12 |      5
2022-01-12 |      5
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Search for "gaps and islands".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8 or MariaDB 10.2, you can use `LEAD()` or `LAG()` to see the next or previous row (given that you have an `ORDER BY`), then you can do the test to see if they are contiguous.  (This is not a "grouping" function.)